# Set proofreading language regardless of keyboard layout

Tags: microsoft-word, keyboard-layout

General info: Windows 11, Office 365, both languages installed in the system as well as in Word.

I use two keyboard layouts (English and Czech), which have completely different punctuation, so even if I write English text, I will mostly want to stay in the Czech layout.

When writing any kind of text in Word, the editor seems to set the language of the text written to that of the current keyboard layout. There are plenty of ways of changing the proofreading language after the text is written, but I have not yet seen a way of changing the default settings so that the text stays in English even if written in a Czech layout.

Is there a way of bypassing this annoying "smart feature" of Word to hardwire the document to be proofread in English regardless of the current keyboard layout?

I have played around with the "Detect language automatically" feature, but it seems to affect only a selected region, which is retrospective by principle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You cannot do this. Word will switch language with the keyboard layout.

There is no option setting. VBA will not do what you want.

**What you can do is:**

1. Have your operating system language set to the primary language that
   you use.
2. Turn off the option in Word to automatically select language.
3. Have your primary language set as the proofing language in your base styles.
4. Create and use paragraph and character styles that have the alternative language.
5. Set keyboard shortcuts for these styles. For character styles, you can use Ctrl+Spacebar to return - to turn off a character style.

Here is a link to my article on [Proofing Language troubleshooting](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/proofing-language-keeps-changing-solutions-how-can/c6483d0c-6fe3-41bf-8464-25535d3ec15b) on the Micrsoft Answers site.

Here is a link to my article on [Assigning Keyboard Shortcuts](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_win10-msoversion_other/assigning-keyboard-shortcuts-in-microsoft-word/a346f277-e0eb-4d17-b53b-233584c611bb?tm=1595883735330) on the Microsoft Answers site.

Comment: This shold not be the accepted anser as it clearly says "You cannot do this". 
Nicola's answer (https://superuser.com/a/1709169/132677) provides the solution for the original question.

Comment: Neither of the other answers tell how to set the proofing language regardless of the keyboard layout. I was simply blunt in saying that this can't be done, because it can't. I suggested a way to be able to proof in Word in the desired language, so do they. They do tell how to change the keyboard layout and system language.

Comment: It worked for me at least on Power Point. I was using the Spanish layout, so Power Point always assumed the text was in Spanish. Now, I set the Language to English, then in Options, the keyboard to Spanish. Now Power Points correctly use English as proofing language.

Answer (score 2):

I've been dealing with this issues for years, and I finally figured it out (Win 10).
Go to language settings => Preferred languages => choose the input language you'd like to use for proofing (English) =>  keyboards
Likely, there is only the English keyboard (QUERTY) listed.
=> Add keyboard => chose the one for Czech.

Now go to Settings => devices => typing => Advanced keyboard settings (at the bottom of the page) => Override for default input method
In the drop down list, besides English - US/UK, there should be an entry English - Czech. Choose this, and there you go!
Or you can switch between input languages and keyboard layouts by using keyboard shortcuts => Chose input language/method English and keyboard layout (QUERTZ).
Hope it works in Win11 as it does in Win10!

Comment: How is this better than accepted answer?

Answer (score 1):

MY FRIEND I have found the one real solution for this. I tried the other comments' advice but I didn't get there by going to 'advanced keyboard options' at all.

I wanted to use Dutch as a proofing language and use a US international layout. Like you said word kept changing it automatically because I was forced to choose US in windows system keyboard input settings to use the layout for the keyboard. So, what you need to do:

Settings > Time & Language > Language.
Scroll down. There is a list of 'preferred languages'.

Say you want to use English for Word to proofread but use Czech layout. Click on English in this list. You now see arrows and the box 'options' and 'remove'. I click on  box 'options'.

Then a new window opens and you see 'Keyboards' at the bottom  Add Czech keyboard FIRST, only after adding that you can REMOVE English keyboard.

Now if you go back to Time & Language > Language click on 'keyboard' icon at the top and select English. It will proofread as English yet stick to Czech layout.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).